# How to cleanly deal with nested Future[Option[A]]

Tags: scala, future

I think this is probably a simple question, but I'm really struggling to get it right, I have the following functions:

```
def getInfo(identifier: Int): Future[Option[Info]]

def deleteInfo(info: Info): Future[Bool]
```

I'm trying to implement the following:

```
def deleteInfoByID(identifier: Int): Future[Bool]
```

I'm wondering what the cleanest way to do this is?  I've tried a few variations on map and flatMap, but I can't seem to propagate the result of deleteInfo back to the top:

```
def deleteInfoByID(identifier: Int): Future[Bool]
    getInfo(identifier).map { infoOpt: Option[Info] =>
      infoOpt.map { info =>
        deleteInfoByID(identifier)
      }
    }
```

Comment: What should be return value of `deleteInfoByID` if no **Info** was found? `false`? - Also, whereas there is nothing wrong with `Future[Option[A]]` some people would prefer to just use `Future[A]` and throw a custom exception if the `A` is missing. I prefer the `Option` but you may be interested in that alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You should rather `flatMap`:

```scala
def deleteInfoByID(identifier: Int): Future[Bool]
  getInfo(identifier).flatMap {
    case Some(id) => deleteInfoByID(id)
    case _ => Future.successful(false)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of `fold()`.

```
def deleteInfoByID(identifier: Int): Future[Boolean] =
  getInfo(identifier)
    .flatMap(_.fold(Future.successful(false))(deleteInfo))
```